# NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML doesn't tidy some XHTML validation errors

Tags: html, objective-c, xml, cocoa, xhtml

I want to grab text from a list of web pages. I've done a bit of experimenting and found that the best way for my needs is via WebKit.

Once the source of the page has been grabbed, I want to strip out all the HTML tags, by using [the technique in this comment.](http://sugarmaplesoftware.com/25/strip-html-tags/#comment-71)

Here's my code:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    if(frame == [sender mainFrame]) {
        NSString *content = [[[[sender mainFrame] dataSource] representation] documentSource];
        NSXMLDocument *theDocument = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:content options:NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML error:&theError];
        NSString *theXSLTString = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>\n<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:xhtml='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>\n<xsl:output method='text'/>\n<xsl:template match='xhtml:head'></xsl:template>\n<xsl:template match='xhtml:script'></xsl:template>\n</xsl:stylesheet>";
        NSData *theData = [theDocument objectByApplyingXSLTString:theXSLTString arguments:nil error:&theError];
        NSString *theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
}
```

This works fine on most pages. However, if a page doesn't validate correctly as XHTML, I sometimes get an error from my `initWithXMLString:` method.

That's fair enough - I'm asking it to tidy up the XHTML, so I'd expect it to report what problems it's encountered. But if there's a problem with the validation, it returns nil and an error rather than actually tidying up the XHTML.

One specific page that's causing the problem is [the Ruby class documentation.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Builder/CSS.html)

I've found that the excellent third party [HTML tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) application can clean up this XHTML fine, but I'd expect NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML to be able to just add some quotes around cellpadding values. It's a fairly basic cleanup operation. And I'm not keen to add another dependency into my code base.

Is there something I'm missing with the way Cocoa cleans up XHTML? Or do I just need to bite the bullet and use HTML Tidy instead in my code?

Comment: I found that this code doesn't always work because -objectByApplyingXSLTString:arguments:error: may return an NSXMLDocument rather than an NSData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XHTML documents are treated as XML, so you may have better luck with the `NSXMLDocumentTidyXML` flag.

Comment: Worth noting that they're not mutually exclusive. You can use NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML | NSXMLDocumentTidyXML to get both behaviors together. TidyXML fixes up invalid XML to be valid; TidyHTML makes the document's string values easier to read.

Comment: Thanks a lot chaps. Really helpful. I tried NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML and NSXMLDocumentTidyXML seperately, but in my frustration forgot to try them together. This did the trick! No more reliance on HTML Tidy for me. Marvellous.