# Manipulating HTML

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, osx-snow-leopard, nsxmldocument

I need to read a HTML file and search for some tags in it. Based on the results, some tags would need to be removed, other ones changed and maybe refining some attributes — to then write the file back.

Is NSXMLDocument the way to go? I don't think that a parser is really needed in this case, it could even mean more work. And I don't want to touch the entire file, all I need to do is to load the file in memory, change some things, and save it again.

Note that, I'll be dealing with HTML, and not XHTML. Could that be a problem for NSXMLDocument? Maybe some unmatched tags or un-closed ones could make it stop working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSXMLDocument is the way to go. That way you can use Xpath/Xquery to find the tags you want.  Bad HTML might be a problem but you can set NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML and it should be OK unless it's really bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSRange startRange = [string rangeOfString:@"<htmlTag>"];
NSRange endRange = [string rangeOfString:@"</htmlTag>"];
NSString *subStr = [string subStringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startRange.location+startRange.length, endRange.location-startRange.location-startRange.length)];
NSString *finalStr = [string stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:substr];
```

and then write finalstr to the file.

This is what I would do, note that I don't exactly know what the advantages of using NSXMLDocument would be, this should do it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

`NSXMLDocument` will possibly fail, due to the fact that HTML pages are not well formed, but you can try with `NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML`/`NSXMLDocumentTidyXML` (you can use them both to improve results) as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032241/nsxmldocumenttidyhtml-doesnt-tidy-some-xhtml-validation-errors) and also have a look a [this](http://sugarmaplesoftware.com/25/strip-html-tags/) for tan approach at modifying the HTML.